# Undeclared identifier for histogram plot [Pine Scripts]

Tags: pine-script

undeclared identifier for histogram plot

i'm just beginner to write a pine script

```
study("My Hong")
spread = high - low
vsa = volume / spread
plot(vsa , style=histogram)
```

I think other ppl has similar script as mine but why my script got undeclared identifier for histogram plot

Comment: Also, next time please add the error message too.

Comment: Actually there is no problem with your code. Just copy and paste it as it is. Do not add anything to it. even a comment. The issue on your tradingview is because u have //@version=4

Answer (score 6):

The histogram style is called `plot.style_histogram`.

Pine-script has a good language reference manual. You can access it within the editor by *Ctrl + click (PC)* or *cmd + click (Mac)* on a keyword.

Try to read the documentation of `plot` function and have a look at the `style` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved. :)

Comment: I keep getting following error: `Error: Undeclared identifier `plot.style_histogram``

Comment: @alper Ask a new question please. Hard to tell you what's going on without seeing your code.